# Converting fractions to decimals NASM

Tags: assembly, nasm

So I have fixed a lot since my last post but I am still not getting the result. We are working on the 8086 microprocessor and NASM assembler. My code works great right up until it is about to give the result. It will display the 3rd message "The number is: " and prints the decimal point, "." but it won't print any numbers after that and I can't type or exit the program or anything. I have to close DOSBox and run it again. Please help.

```
       org 100h
; program converts fraction, M/N, to decimal, where M < N, M & N are both positive, and upto 6 decimal places are printed
section .data
MSG1    db  "Enter the numerator: ", '$'
MSG2    db  "Enter the denominator: ", '$'
MSG3    db  "The number is: ", '$'
EMSG    db  "Please enter a number between 0 and 9 ", '$'
section .bss
M   RESb    1   
N   RESb    1

section .text
main:
; print user prompt 
mov     dx, MSG1    ; get message
mov     ah, 09h     ; display string function
int     21h         ; display it
call    DEC_IN      
mov     [M], bx     ; move numerator to memory location M
; print second prompt
mov     dl, 0Ah     ; line feed moved into character display register
mov     ah, 02h     ; charcter display function
int     21h         ; display line feed
mov     dl, 0Dh     ; carriage return moved into character display register
int     21h         ; display carriage return
mov     dx, MSG2    ; get message
mov     ah, 09h     ; display string function
int     21h         ; display it
call    DEC_IN
mov     [N], bx     ; store denominator in memory location N
mov     dl, 0Ah     ; line feed moved into character display register
mov     ah, 02h     ; charcter display function
int     21h         ; display line feed
mov     dl, 0Dh     ; carriage return moved into character display register
int     21h         ; display carriage return
mov     dx, MSG3    ; get message
mov     ah, 09h     ; display string function
int     21h         ; display it
mov     dl, 2Eh     ; moves '.' to display character register
mov     ah, 02h     ; display character function
int     21h         ; displays it
mov     cx, 6       ; set loop to run 6 times
mov     bx, [M]     ; prepare numerator in M to be multiplied
jmp     print
DEC_IN:
; input character from keyboard, converts ASCII to appropriate binary
push    ax
xor     bx,bx
.top:
mov     ah, 01h     ; keyboard input function
int     21h         ; character input, copies character into al
cmp     al, 0Dh     ; is the input a carriage return?
je      .done       ; user is done
cmp     al, 30h     ; compares input to ASCII code for 0
jb      error       ; if input is less than 0 jump to error
cmp     al, 39h     ; compares input to ASCII code for 9
ja      error       ; if input is greater than 9 jump to error
sub     al, 30h     ; subtracts 30h to make the ASCII code into the base 10 number
imul    bx, 10      ; in case the number is more than one digit
mov     ah, 0       ; clear ah before copy
add     bx, ax      ; store ax in bx so it can run again.
jmp     .top
.done:
pop     ax
ret

print:
; loop to print 
mov     al, 10      ; prepare al for multiplication
mul     bx          ; multiply numerator by 10, result in AX
mov     bx, [N]     ; move denominator to bx to be divisor
div     bx          ; divide AX by denominator quotient in AL remainder in AH
add     al, 30h     ; convert quotient to respective ASCII symbol
mov     dl, al      ; move quotient into display char register
push    ax          ; save the remainder in AH by pushing AX on stack
mov     ah, 02h     ; display character function
int     21h         ; display it    
pop     ax          ; retrieve remainder in AH by popping AX from stack
mov     al, 0       ; clear the quotient, AL so only the remainder, AH, is in AX 
mov     bx, ax      ; move remainder to bx so it can run again
loop    print
jmp     exit

error:
; displays error message then jumps back to DEC_IN
mov     dl, 0Ah     ; line feed moved into character display register
mov     ah, 02h     ; charcter display function
int     21h         ; display line feed
mov     dl, 0Dh     ; carriage return moved into character display register
int     21h         ; display carriage return
mov     dx, EMSG    ; moves error message into display string register
mov     ah, 09h     ; display string function
int     21h         ; displays it
mov     dl, 0Ah     ; line feed moved into character display register
mov     ah, 02h     ; charcter display function
int     21h         ; display line feed
mov     dl, 0Dh     ; carriage return moved into character display register
int     21h         ; display carriage return
jmp     main        

exit:
;exit to DOS
 mov     ah, 04Ch      ; DOS function: Exit program 
 mov     al, 0         ; Return exit code value
 int     21h           ; Call DOS. Terminate program
```

Comment: @KenWhite I thought cx was the loop count register, and that the loop instruction automatically decrements cx. also even if it was an infinite loop it should still be printing the numbers after the decimal point, just forever instead of just 6 decimal places which is what I set cx to just before the start of the loop (print:)

Comment: Yep, I think you're right - I missed it. I said my asm was rusty. :-)

Comment: Well I was able to get it to print the number in the first decimal place! I added `xor ax,ax` just before jumping to routine "print:"

Answer (score 1):

ok I fixed it. Those 16 bit registers are tricky so I used 8 bit registers for the multiplication and division. The only thing I had to fix was routine `print:` the rest of the code is the same, except that in `main:` the last instruction before the jump to `print:` was changed to `mov bl,[m]`. here is the corrected routine `print:`:

```
print:
; loop to print 
xor     ax, ax      ; clear ax
mov     al, 10      ; prepare for multiplication
mul     bl          ; multiply numerator in BL by 10 in AL
xor     bl, bl      ; clear bl to be used again
mov     bl, [N]     ; move denominator in to BL
div     bl          ; divide numerator*10 in AX by denominator in BL
mov     dl, al      ; move quotient in AL to display char register
push    ax          ; save the remainder in AH
add     dl, 30h     ; convert quotient to respective ASCII symbol
xor     ax, ax      ; clear ax for function
mov     ah, 02h     ; display char function
int     21h         ; display it    
pop     ax          ; retrieve remainder in AH
mov     bl, ah      ; move remainder to BL to start loop over
loop    print
jmp     exit
```